# Database error Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting

Tags: database

I’m getting this message in my error logs from the time i have enabled autoptimize. The full message is as follows:

> [23-Feb-2020 06:56:27 UTC] WordPress database error Deadlock found
>   when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction for query DELETE
>   FROM wp_options WHERE option_name =
>   ‘_transient_timeout_autoptimize_cache_warmer_protector’ made by
>   require(‘wp-blog-header.php’), require_once(‘wp-load.php’),
>   require_once(‘wp-config.php’), require_once(‘wp-settings.php’),
>   do_action(‘init’), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters,
>   autoclear_autoptimize_cache, autoptimizeCache::clearall,
>   get_transient, delete_option

Please can anyone tell me and help me out as to how can i fix this.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Do you see any other errors in debug.log? If debugging is not enabled, can you possibly enable it and check for any other errors you might be getting in there?